# JWT - what algorithm "harder to hack"

Tags: encryption, jwt

With JWT based authentication, algorithm can be [HS512,HS384, HS256 ...]

My question is:

1. The HS512 algorithm "harder to hack" than HS256 ?
2. Why they coexist

Comment: Which hash algorithm is chosen will not make any real difference in the security or performance, they are all essentially as secure. The attacks will come from another direction.

Comment: That is an interesting question, consider asking on [Crypto Stackexchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com). This is more of an implementation forum, Crypto StackExchange is more about Cryptography.

Comment: This is not about hashing passwords, HS256/HS512 is about a keyed-hash message authentication code to achieve integrity and authentication; as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code says: "The cryptographic strength of the HMAC depends upon the cryptographic strength of the underlying hash function, the size of its hash output, and on the size and quality of the key." Assuming  the hash function and the key are fixed, SHA 512 is stronger and thus "harder to hack".

Comment: 3DES has a 168-bit key yet is less secure than AES with a 128-bit key.

Comment: @HansZ. no one is attacking the hash, that is not possible, they are attacking the potential message and the message may be a password.

Comment: It is not a password, it is a JWT, also we are comparing HS512 with HS256, so same algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes, the output is larger and thus harder to "guess", see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions HS512 uses the SHA-512 hashing algorithm, HS256 uses SHA-256
2. because different target environments need different forms of security and each form has its own cost in terms of processing and size overhead; e.g. a SHA-512 hash output is twice the size of a SHA-256 hash output, takes twice as much memory/storage and a lot more processing overhead

Comment: thank you @Hans Z, by the way, if my secret-key contain unicode string  like `ξưệ` that will make any more harder to "guess" ?

Comment: I would not call 139 to 154 MiB/s a lot more processing overhead, ~11% slower and thus ~11% harder to "guess".

Comment: 11% slower to produce the digest, agreed, but a lot more processing is needed to produce a collision

Comment: @HansZ. you won't produce a collision, as far as we know no one has yet. Find one and become famous.

Comment: Great that you agree that it is harder to find a collision for sha512

Comment: Worthless but not wrong and not much more resource intensive. It does look uninformed though.